# What is the top bar height of iPhone X?

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone-x

I would like to know exact height of top bar of iPhone X.
Could you please mention the **status bar and navigation bar height of iPhone X.**
Please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 94, accepted):

> The display on iPhone X, however, is **145pt** taller than a 4.7" display, resulting in roughly 20% additional vertical space for content.

for more information you get HIG for iphone X from apple [documents](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/iphone-x/) and detail description in [here1](https://blog.prototypr.io/designing-for-the-iphone-x-4239d5ac736c) and [here2](https://medium.com/@hacknicity/how-ios-apps-adapt-to-the-iphone-x-screen-size-a00bd109bbb9)

[image]

**status bar height**

**previously 20pt, now 44pt**

> Because of the sensors on top of the display, the new status bar is split in 2 parts. If your UI is doing something special with that space (previously 20pt high, now 44pt), because it will be taller on the iPhone X. Make sure that it can be dynamically changed in height. A great thing is that the height won’t be changed if a user makes a phone call or is using a navigation app, which was previously the case on other iPhones.

[image]

**portrait**

**Navigation bar height** as normal **88** and large title time **140**

- **Standard title - 44pt (88pt with Status Bar)**
- **Large title   - 140pt**
- **bottom bar  - 34pt**

**Landscape**

- **Standard title - 32pt**
- **bottom bar  - 21pt**

Comment: Typo: Navigation bar height as normal is 44pt.  If you include the status bar then yes it's 88pt.

Answer (score 28):

Nav bar is 44pt as usual (when no large titles) and the status bar has increased from 20pt to 44pt.  Here's what you can type in the debugger to verify it:

[image]

Comment: Why screenshot? -.-

Answer (score 16):

You can programmatically obtain the navigation bar's height by using `safeAreaInsets` on the `view` in the contained view controller:

```
let navBarHeight = view.safeAreaInsets.top
```

This will account for whether it's a large title navigation bar or not, and whether or not there's a search bar attached to it.

See the [`safeAreaInsets` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891103-safeareainsets) for more information.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the navigation bar's .frame property to figure out the overall height of the top bar area:

Swift 5.0:

```
let xBarHeight = (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height ?? 0.0) + (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.origin.y ?? 0.0)
```

ObjC:

```
CGRect navbarFrame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
float topWidth  = navbarFrame.size.width;
float topHeight = navbarFrame.size.height + navbarFrame.origin.y;
```

I suppose this is a bit of a cheat, but adding the navbar's height with its y origin seems to give the correct total height regardless of device.

Comment: Nice solution. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

You can simply get it in the next way (Swift 3):

```
let barHeight = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.maxY
```

To get correct value make sure that you call it after setting `prefersLargeTitles`

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no specification in Apple Docs

[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/bars/navigation-bars/)

According to [Geoff Hackworth](https://medium.com/@hacknicity/how-ios-apps-adapt-to-the-iphone-x-screen-size-a00bd109bbb9) its 88

Navigation title types :

- Standard title
- Large title

Increasing navigation bar in iOS 11

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a UIWindow and you need to know the top bar height you can use this:

```
// old way of getting keyWindow
//guard let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else { return }

// new way of getting keyWindow
guard let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow }) else { return }

let navBarHeight = keyWindow.safeAreaInsets.top

print("navBarHeight:" , navBarHeight)
```

I got the idea from [@Paolo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47212157/4833705)

Answer (score 0):

Use it if you want to know where need start content

```
extension UIViewController {
  var navigationBarbarContentStart: CGFloat {
    return self.navigationBarTopOffset + self.navigationBarHeight
  }
  var navigationBarTopOffset: CGFloat {
    return self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.origin.y ?? 0
  }

  var navigationBarHeight: CGFloat {
    return self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0
  }
}
```