# Iphone X Custom Navigation Support, Tab Bar Size

Tags: ios, iphone-x

In my application I am using custom Navigation bar which loads from XIB,

As Iphone X has different Status Bar and Top Bar what are the changes need to make?

Or it will run normally?

Is status bar color is still relevant?

Also has changes for `Tabbar`?

[image: iphone x sizes]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46198535/5461400

Answer (score 1):

If you were keeping navigation bar's height `64` in old devices then for `iPhone x` you can set that height to `145` as [apple human interface guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/iphone-x/) said that it have `145` points of height for top bar!

And yes status bar color will also relevant I think!

**Edit**

According to [Geoff Hackworth's post](https://medium.com/@hacknicity/how-ios-apps-adapt-to-the-iphone-x-screen-size-a00bd109bbb9)

I think 140 is for large navigation bar titles in iOS 11 and iPhone x !

and for normal it should be `88`

Comment: Thank you for your reply I understood it, Please check edit

Comment: According to this site https://medium.com/@hacknicity/how-ios-apps-adapt-to-the-iphone-x-screen-size-a00bd109bbb9  it shows 88  Why ? There is confusion

Comment: That's not correct. `145` is the screen height difference in points between the iPhone 8 and the iPhone X, and not the navigation bar height.