# Default navigation style is misplaced for iOS 11

Tags: swift, ios11, navigationbar

In my application I am using below code to add default navigation.

[image]

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = // my color
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = // my color
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

This code works fine till iOS 10. But in iOS 11 the back icon is not in the center.

I checked other similar issues regarding view title [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46578752/ios-11-navigation-titleview-misplaced) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365620/how-to-set-large-title-on-navigation-bar-for-ios-11) but couldn't find any solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46209423/4290431) answer and I did the same.

Removing this line from `AppDelegate` works for me.

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment (UIOffsetMake(0, -60), for: .default)
```