# Huge navigation bar on the iPhone

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to learn how to programmatically create the UI of my application.
I added to the application a navigation controller with code, this is the code:

AppDelegate:

```
    var window: UIWindow?
var navigationController: UINavigationController?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    if let window = window{
        let mainVC = MainVC()
        navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainVC)
        window.rootViewController = navigationController

        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    return true
}
```

And this is my mainVC:

```
    class MainVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blue
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        navigationItem.title = "Hello"
        setupTextBox()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    let textBox: UITextField = {
        var tBox = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 30))
        tBox.placeholder = "Please Enter Name"
        tBox.textAlignment = .center
        tBox.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        tBox.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        return tBox
    }()

    private func setupTextBox(){
        view.addSubview(textBox)
    }
}
```

The navigation bar does appear but it is huge, couldn't find a way to view it as it should be.
This is the image of the navigation bar:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true - this line makes your navbar huge, or i dont understand your question

Comment: Oh, Thanks, I feel kinda stupid now :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because of `navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true`

You are doing well
Just must to understand that it is iPhone X with top safe area + LARGE TITLE

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything wrong. That's simply how a `UINavigationBar` looks on iPhone X, iPhone XR and iPhone XS. All of these devices have the "X" bevel.

Here's another helpful SO post: [What is the top bar height of iPhone X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46197660/what-is-the-top-bar-height-of-iphone-x)

Answer (score 1):

The large navigation bar is a style of navigation bar that is used when prefersLargeTitles is set.  So this line is causing your issue

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

Change that to false and you should get a smaller* navigation bar

Note: * it will still be larger than normal due to the 'notch' on the iPhone X range of devices